# I have deleted some answers of mine in the past - should I be worried about a ban?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, deleted-comments

In the past, whenever I answered a question and then realized that either I had not understood the question correctly or that someone else's answer covers the question better, I would delete my answer.

Then, I read in another meta post that apparently you can get banned for deleting your own posts. I haven't deleted any answer of mine since (though I frequently delete comments, for similar reasons) but I know that in the future, if I post a low quality answer I will either delete it or leave it (fearing for a ban) and feel uncomfortable about its existence.

**Should I be worried about getting banned in the long term? Are the effects of deleting posts permanent, or do they diminish with time and/or positive contributions?** Does deleting (unanswered) questions of mine count, too? Does deleting my comments count?

Comment: You have a little over 300 answers in total with a reasonable average score. Unless you are deleting (or planning to delete) more than half of them, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: @BoltClock Good to know, thank you! What about comments?

Comment: Comments will never count.

Comment: Yes, ban diminishes with positive contribution.

Comment: Comments? *Delete them all!* Bwahahaha!!! ;)

Comment: What this site needs is more deleting and editing.  You get on here every day the insane situation where person A will post an answer.  Someone will immediately point out, in a comment, that there is a bad error in the answer.  Then ... person "A" will post a comment saying "oh, gee, yes, you're quite right! thanks for pointing that out!"  it's like "hit the edit button, stupid!"  And indeed, delete comments without hesitation if they are no longer relevant

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No no... it's not even close.

You're a hobby programmer, you have almost 300 answers including some pretty good ones. You don't post lots of junk questions ("vamp") or junk answers on "popular" topic ("rep wh**e").

- Deleting an answer when you figure you haven't understood the question is perfectly fine, I do it from time to time and I've noticed a lot of other users do it. It's helpful and it keeps the site clean.
- Deleting comments is *positive*, comments are *meant* to be eventually deleted.

**Bans are very hard to get when you use the system right**, you shouldn't be *anywhere* even close to a question or answer ban. Stack Overflow wants *more* users with your usage profile not less.

Comment: I probably have around 200 deleted answers (almost 25%) and I'm not banned from answering. Though I'd need a moderator to tell me exactly how many.

Comment: Does answer deletion even contribute to ban score, or only question deletion? I don't see many cases where answer deletion would be abusive unless you're just trying to eliminate bad rep, but it's hard to get a net negative score from an answer anyway. Where deletion is more of a problem is with students asking for answers to their homework then deleting the question once they get an answer so that their classmates (or instructor) can't see the answer (or that they asked).

Comment: @R.. There are separate bans for questions and answers. It's just a lot harder to hit the answer ban.

Comment: @R.. [You can get answer banned](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) for posting a lot of low quality question. This can happen when users do not understand the system (and can't reason about it like you) and then answer a lot of questions with junk (like copy paste from the first google result for keywords related to the question) in order to net rep. When/if they get downvoted, they delete the answers. Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179924/210016

Comment: What is the reason deleting an answer might count against someone? If someone sees that their bad answer is getting negative score, and that motivates them to delete it, doesn't that improve the site?

Comment: @Tenfour04 if it happens often enough, the site might be further improved if they couldn't post that answer to begin with.

Comment: @JacobRaihle So the fear is that some people will post weak answers like crazy to get a few points here and there and just take down the ones that get negative rep?

Comment: But.. SHOULD you get an answer ban if you say `more users with your usage profile not less.` instead of `more users with your usage profile not fewer.`? ;)

Comment: "comments are meant to be eventually deleted" - Surely that isn't the case in general.  Comments are often an important part of the exchange and a valuable part of the site.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown they're not supposed to, comments are meant to encourage an edit to the question or answer, once the edit is performed they should be deleted. At least in _theory_.

Comment: "comments are meant to encourage an edit to the question or answer".  I did not realize that.  I am glad that a lot of folks don't adhere to that.

Comment: I was curious and found this in the help as part of describing what comments are used for. "Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post".  I am glad that folks do that.

Answer (score 13):

About "I had not understood the question correctly" reason to delete: unless your answer is completely off (i.e. because question is clarified to exclude your interpretation of the post) and can no longer be one that found by search for something related I'd consider editing instead and add your understanding of the question.

Even if you are deleting an answer consider editing in a reason/your interpretation of question - this may help others (even if 10K+ only) to avoid re-posting answer with the same misinterpretation of question.

Obviously if you post did not took you any effort to write - delete and be done with it.

Comment: Interesting concept.

Comment: This is in fact asking a different question in an answer post, and answering it in the same post - what a mess. I understand that you refer to a situation when this different interpretation is *very very* close to the initial question. But unless it's *very very* close I'd consider rather asking and self-answering a different question. You still can link between these question as *related* in the comments or posts, so no context and important information is lost.